# If $Y$ is a countable scattered normal space of $X$, is $hl(\overline{Y})=d(\overline{Y})$?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $Y$ is a scattered normal space of some space $X$ and $Y$ is countable. Then do we have that $hl(\overline{Y})=d(\overline{Y})$? hl denotes hereditarily lindelof number and $d$ denotes the density. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take $Y = [0,1]^R$, and let $D$ be a countable dense subset of $X$ (Hewitt-Marczewski-Pondiczery theorem). Let $X$ be $Y$ as a set, but refine the product topology to make all points of $D$ isolated. Using $D = Y$ we have that the closure is $X$ itself, which is separable but not hereditarily Lindelöf. And $D$ is a countable discrete space, so certainly normal and scattered.